# How to fix KeyError in Python dataframe that was read in from a CSV file?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to Python and am having trouble reading a CSV file into a pandas dataframe as shown below. I get a KeyError when I try to reference the first column ('Invoice ID '). It shows up when I run df.columns. However, when I run df['Invoice ID '], I get a KeyError, and when I run 'Invoice ID ' in df.columns, it returns false.  How can I fix this, so I can pull the first column without returning a KeyError?

```
SEC_df = pd.read_csv(SEC_file, header=1)
SEC_df.columns

Index(['Invoice ID ', 'Invoice Number ', 'Contact.Contact ID ',
       'Contact.Name ', 'Date ', 'Due Date ', 'Branding Theme ID ', 'Status ',
       'Line Amount Types ', 'Sub Total ', 'Total Tax ', 'Total ',
       'Updated Date UTC ', 'Currency Code ', 'Fully Paid On Date ', 'Type ',
       'Amount Paid ', 'Amount Due ', 'Amount Credited ', 'Sent To Contact ',
       'Currency Rate ', 'Has Attachments ', 'Line Items.Line Item ID ',
       'Line Items.Description ', 'Line Items.Unit Amount ',
       'Line Items.Tax Type ', 'Line Items.Tax Amount ',
       'Line Items.Line Amount ', 'Line Items.Account Code ',
       'Line Items.Item Code ', 'Line Items.Quantity '],
      dtype='object')


'Invoice ID ' in SEC_df.columns

False


SEC_df['Invoice ID ']


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Invoice ID '

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-3e9c7cc16ac6> in <module>
----> 1 SEC_df['Invoice ID ']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Invoice ID '
```

Comment: Pretty weird, it seems like you've got it right. Curious, does this problem occur for the other columns as well?

Comment: I wonder if there some of those spaces are in some way non-standard. You might try `SEC_df.columns = map(str.strip, SEC_df.columns)` then try to access something like `'Date'` that does not contain spaces between words.

Comment: The map function did the trick.  Thanks very much, @brentertainer